# Getting UnicodeDecodeError when using shap on xgboost

Tags: python, python-3.x, xgboost

I'm trying to use shap on xgboost model, but getting error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 341: invalid start byte
```

example:

```
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
```

package versions:

```
    python == 3.6.9
    xgboost==1.1.0
    shap==0.35.0
```

What is the problem and how can we fix it ?

Comment: what is the line which is causing this error?

Comment: explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the system.  See: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/1215.
The issue seems to be resolved, but perhaps the fix is not yet released.  At any rate, I had the same issue and resolved it temporarily by installing xgboost v1.0.0.

Answer (score 5):

I tried the following solution and it worked.

```
package versions:
    python == 3.7.7
    xgboost==1.1.1
    shap==0.35.0
```

The code has worked very well for me.

```
import shap
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier

xgb = XGBClassifier(random_state=42)
mymodel = xgb.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

`The part that really solves them is this, must not miss`

```
mybooster = mymodel.get_booster()    
model_bytearray = mybooster.save_raw()[4:]
def myfun(self=None):
    return model_bytearray
mybooster.save_raw = myfun

# Shap explainer initilization
shap_ex = shap.TreeExplainer(mybooster)
```

Comment: The answer is not only the first line, since everything as a whole is the answer, from version 1.0.0 of xgboost there is an update in the data structure and it is necessary to create model_bytearray and save it in the model as a function that would be myfun(), before using it by the TreeExplainer function.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with `xgboost-1.2.0` and `shap 0.35.0`.

Here is the complete example that I was able to run without problem:

```
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
import shap

# data
np.random.seed(100)
X_train = np.random.random((100, 10))
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=100)

# model
model = xgb.XGBClassifier(random_state=42)
fitted_model = model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# monkey patch
booster = fitted_model.get_booster() 
model_bytearray = booster.save_raw()[4:]
booster.save_raw = lambda : model_bytearray

# shap expaliner
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(booster)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_train)
```

## output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
!pip install shap==0.36.0
!pip install xgboost==1.3.3
```

This worked for me well